# Carrierwave remove picture and set back to default

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I'm using Rails 3 with carrierwave gem.

I managed to removed the avatar image from my user model like this:

```
@user.remove_photo!
```

and it works perfectly. However, I want to set the picture url for that user back to the default_url (which is the image that every user has until they upload one).

Any ideas how?

--

Image display code:

```
<%= image_tag(@user.photo.send(:layout).url, :alt => @user.full_name, :class => 'photo large') %>
```

default_url code:

```
def default_url
    "default_photo.jpg"
  end
```

Comment: I would not set the default photo in the users avatar.  I would have the image in your static assets and do an if statement that shows the default image if the user image doesn't exist.

Comment: Actually that's the only solution I can think of. I was wondering if the gem had any way to set the picture back to the default.

Comment: Paste your code for displaying the image, and paste your code for your def url

Comment: there you go @fatfrog

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

> In many cases, especially when working with images, it might be a good
>   idea to provide a default url, a fallback in case no file has been
>   uploaded. You can do this easily by overriding the default_url method
>   in your uploader:

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def default_url
    "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end
end
```

> Or if you are using the Rails asset pipeline:

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def default_url
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  end
end
```

Comment: No, you didn't understand my issue. I already have that. The issue is go back to the default_url AFTER I deleted a photo.

Comment: You aren't following the code, it should be "/"+ [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')

Answer (score 0):

You need to force update the field in the database to null, after that carrierwave will use the default_url, you can do this by calling `Model.where(<CONDITIONS>).update_all(photo: nil)` or `instance.update_column(photo: nil)`